# Как определить, есть ли в строке указанные символы?

Tags: php

люди добрые) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно определить наличие лишних символов в строке? Строка должна состоять только из 1) русских строчных и прописных букв и пробелов или же 2) слова из русских букв с заглавной буквы (или же двух слов с заглавных букв с дефисом между ними)

Т.е. строка - это либо ФИО вместе, либо фамилия, имя и отчество по отдельности.

читал про preg_match, но что-то толком шаблон не могу составить. И вообще туплю по-страшному. Или же, может, можно как-то сравнением символов из массива... Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем, решение такое...

```
if (preg_match('/^[а-яё ]++$/ui', $name)) {
    echo 'Правильно: '.$name; 
}else{
    echo 'НЕПРАВИЛЬНО: '.$name; 
}
```

Точно ещё пока не разобрался что к чему, но работает. Только не определяет заглавные ли первые буквы слов

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[А-Я][а-я]*([-][А-Я][а-я]*)?\s[А-Я][а-я]*\s[А-Я][а-я]*$/
```

Comment: А локаль не надо никакую устанавливать? Спасибо за ответ. Пока нет возможности проверить. Вечером отпишусь.

Comment: @Руслан что локально устанавливать ?

Comment: Не локально) Где-то читал, что нужно определить в коде локаль. Команда setlocale. Не исключено, конечно, что я не на том сконцентрировался

Comment: ничего не выходит. Толи лыжи не едут, толи я дурачок.
$slovo = 'абв14.,г';
 
if (preg_match('/^[А-Я][а-я]*([-][А-Я][а-я]*)?\s[А-Я][а-я]*\s[А-Я][а-я]*$/', $slovo)) {
    echo "не то((";
}else{
    echo "ОКККК!!!";
}

При любом слове выводит "ОКККК!!!"

Comment: Локаль, и в самом деле, не нужно устанавливать